# put submit button in Tabs::widget in yii2

Tags: forms, tabs, yii2, widget

I have a Tabs::widget that all settings are located in different tabs in a ActiveForm and admin can set config in each tab and once submit.(multiple forms in one widget )

in setting view :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?php

echo \yii\jui\Tabs::widget([
'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'tabs'],
'itemOptions' => ['tag' => 'div'],
'items' => [
    [
        'label' => 'serverSetting',
        'content' => $this->render('serverSetting', ['model' => $model, 'form' => $form]),
        'active' => true
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'emailSetting',
        'content' => $this->render('emailSetting', ['model' => $model, 'form' => $form]),
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'smsSetting',
        'content' => $this->render('smsSetting', ['model' => $model, 'form' => $form]),
    ],
],
]);

?>
  <div class="btnForm">
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'ثبت', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => ''])) ?>
 </div>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

in view of one of the tabs (smsServer view):

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\components\ActiveForm;
?>
<div class="user-form">

<?= $form->field($model, 'login')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'host']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password1')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'username']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'wsdl')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'password']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'from1')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'port']) ?>
</div>
```

in controller :

```
public function actionSetting()
{
    $model = new Setting();
    $model->setAttributes(Yii::$app->params, false);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        file_put_contents(Yii::getAlias('@app/config') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extra_params.php', base64_encode(serialize($model->attributes)));
    }
    return $this->render('setting', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

My form and submit button do not work. where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't have an `ActiveForm::end()`

```
 .......
  <div class="btnForm">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'ثبت', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])) ?>
  </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

*and for debugging don't suppress the name of button*

Answer (score 0):

So I found my answer. My validation was false.

in rule():

```
 [['login', 'wsdl', 'password','from1'], 'required',],
```

But I post form without filled all fields.

I changed to

```
[['login',], 'required',],

[['login', 'wsdl', 'password',from1'], 'safe',],
```